# what a server side will do for a REST API request?

Tags: rest, server

I am a junior for programming and i am work on REST API, I have a question as the title shows. I mean, how does a server process a REST API request? create a new file and store data in the new-created file? store data in a single（only one）file like a Database does？
For example：

POST http://www.example.com/customers

POST http://www.example.com/customers/12345/orders

what a server will do with these two request? 
any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The server will do whatever it has been programmed to do - store data in a database, or a file, or somewhere else... it really depends on how it was built

Comment: do you mean that in server we can define the any operation with the data contained in request?

Comment: Yup, pretty much. There are rules regarding REST requests (a GET request should not alter the server's state, a POST request should) but how they are implemented on server side, is up to the server

Answer (score 0):

`POST` is HTTP's most unconstrained method: it can do anything. The disadvantage is that requests are neither idempotent nor safe, which means that clients cannot safely repeat requests without risking unintended side-effects.

For a little while, the HTTP spec was worded a bit strange saying that "POST creates a child resource." That has been cleaned up in the updated version, and now `POST` really is described as the unconstrained method that it is: A server can do anything, meaning it can store, or process, or do anything else.

HTTP/1.1 Semantics: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3

GET and PUT are a bit different because when using them, the assumption is that they can be used idempotently (`GET`) or safely (`PUT`). Other HTTP methods also fit into this framework of being idempotent, safe, or none of those.

Not that I would recommend to do this ever, but in theory you could have a working HTTP REST API only using `POST`, because `POST` really can do anything. But this would be a very badly designed API, that would lack a lot of the advantages that well-designed HTTP REST APIs have.

Comment: can you link the documents you are referring to?

Comment: added link to HTTP spec. but if you ask about HTTP,  shouldn't you be able to google the spec yourself?

Comment: I ask for the spec that says "post is described as the unconstraind method"

Comment: that's the HTTP/1.1 spec i linked to. quoting the linked section: "The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics." no further constraints are defined for what those semantics can or cannot do. POST is REST's catch-all.